# Especific terms at Formal Concept Analysis - Translate to Portuguese

Tags: formal-languages, translation-request

I am taking a course of *Introduction to Formal Concept Analysis* and, as this is my first time with this topic, I could not translate very well some especific terms to portuguese. I hope someone could help me, please.

For instance, the name of the course:

**Introduction to Formal Concept Analysis**.

Should I translate by:

*Análise de Conceitos Formais*, right?

I think I won't use *Análise Formal de Conceitos*, because the concepts are formal, not the analysis... Right?

And about the terms **intension** and **closure operators/systems**. What do you think is the better translate? These last, I think *operadores/sistema de fechamento*, but I'm not sure

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original German name is "Formale Begriffsanalyse", which is "formal analysis of concepts".

So, the correct is "Análise Formal de Conceitos"  (credit to my professor Sergei).

About "intension", using the correct name for the topic, I could find an archive in Portuguese and the translate is "intensão". I was thinking that is little bit strange because we almost do not use this word, but it's correct this case.